# Remove Tenant from (Custom) Login Page

Tags: abp

Just getting started with the APB Framework (using mvc and SQL Server) so bear with this newbie.

I have turned off the use of Tenants.

Then following this article [How to Customize the Login Page for MVC / Razor Page Applications](https://community.abp.io/articles/how-to-customize-the-login-page-for-mvc-razor-page-applications-9a40f3cd) I created a custom login page but the TENANT selection box is still appearing and it's not in the cshtml

The question is so how do I remove the Tenant box from the page??

*EDIT: Well my flag was still set to true, so never mind!*

Comment: OMG do I feel stupid, the flag was still set to true! I changed it BACK to false and it's now gone. So please ignore this

Comment: You can delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must go to **Domain.Shared->MultiTenancy->MultiTenancyConsts.cs**
and change the below value to false

**public const bool IsEnabled = false;**

[document link](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy#abpmultitenancyoptions-enable-disable-multi-tenancy)